# Distribution of cumulated intensity for Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

I've come across a statement in a textbook that is not proved, and I have a hard time coming up with the proof myself.

Let $\tau$ be the first jump of a (time inhomogeneous) Poisson process with intensity $\lambda(t)$. Define the *cumulated intensity*: $\Lambda(t):=\int_0^t\lambda(u) \, du$

The claim the authors make (which I want to see a proof of) is:

> One of the important facts about Poisson processes is a property of the jump time $\tau$ according to its own cumulated intensity $\Lambda$. We have
>
> $\Lambda(\tau)=:\xi \sim $ exponential standard random variable.

(If anyone is interested, the book is Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice
2nd ed. by Brigo and Mercurio, where this statement is found on page 698)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inhomogeneous Poisson process the probability that there are no jumps on the interval $[0,y]$ is 
$$
\mathbb P(\tau >y) = e^{-\Lambda(y)}
$$
Recall that the distribution of $\tau$ is absolutely continuous and the pdf can be obtained from the above equality.

Since the function $\Lambda(t)$ is continuous and non-decreasing, we can define  inverse of it as 
$$
\Lambda^{-1}(x) = \inf\{t: \Lambda(t)\geq x\}.
$$
Note that $\Lambda(\tau)\geq x$ $\iff$ $\tau\geq\Lambda^{-1}(x)$.

Then
$$
\mathbb P(\Lambda(\tau)\geq x) = \mathbb P(\tau\geq\Lambda^{-1}(x))=\mathbb P(\tau >\Lambda^{-1}(x)) = e^{-\Lambda(\Lambda^{-1}(x))} = e^{-x}.
$$
So the distribution of $\xi=\Lambda(\tau)$ is standard exponential.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(\xi >x) \\[10pt]
= {}& \Pr(\Lambda(\tau) > \Lambda(t)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr\big((\text{number of jumps before time $t$}) = 0\big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\Lambda(t)^0 e^{-\Lambda(t)}}{0!} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-\Lambda(t)} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-x}.
\end{align}

Comment: What if $t$ in the first equality? Is it a solution of $\Lambda(t)=x$? Which one?

Comment: @NCh : There will be more than one such solution only if the intesity is $0$ on some interval, and then (as should be apparent from what I wrote) it don'es matter which of the solutions you pick, since at the end you still get $e^{-x}. \qquad$

Comment: And in this case the first equality looks doubtful. The events under probability are not equal.

Comment: @NCh : The events differ by an event of probability zero. $\qquad$